# command line SET in nested IF/ELSE

Tags: command-line, nested, set

I need to initialize multiple env vars only on certain conditions, I cannot use anything but command line.
For the example of my problem I am going to take a symple case of initializing an alphabet.

First cmd script is :

```
@echo OFF
set PATH=%PATH%;"%~dp0"
IF "%_ALPHABET%"=="" (
    echo "DEFINE"
    call setEnvA
    call set "_ALPHABET=%_ALPHABET%;b"
) ELSE (
    echo "ALREADY DEFINE"
    set _ALPHABET=
    set A_ADDED=
)
```

setEnvA cmd is :

```
IF "%A_ADDED%"=="" (
    set A_ADDED=OK
    set _ALPHABET=%_ALPHABET%;a
)
```

I was expecing

```
;a;b
```

as a result, but I get only

```
;b
```

I tried to throw random delayedexpansion but without any result. I am starting to think that this is not possible and I should do some dirty goto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The contents of environment variable _ALPHABET is being substituted within the parenthesis *before* the call to setEnvA is performed.  You need to do something like:

```
@echo OFF
set PATH=%PATH%;"%~dp0"
IF "%_ALPHABET%"=="" (
    echo "DEFINE"
    call setEnvA
    call :set_ALPHABET
) ELSE (
    echo "ALREADY DEFINE"
    set _ALPHABET=
    set A_ADDED=
)
exit /b

:set_ALPHABET
set "_ALPHABET=%_ALPHABET%;b"
```

Comment: thanks Paul! The only problem with the current code answer is the exit (because I need to stay in the process) but I'll figure a way.

Comment: @paulc  **exit /b**  terminates only the script, not the process -- it's equivalent to **goto :eof**.